# JavaScript: function call vs constructor function

Tags: javascript, function, oop, constructor

In JavaScript I can call objects, for example; `String`, `Number` and `Boolean` in two different ways, one as a standard function call, the other as a constructor.

**Example**

```
// Call String as a standard function call.
var a = String("Hello World");
// a = "Hello World";

// Call String as a constructor function.
var b = new String("Hello World");
// b = String {0: "H", 1: "e", 2: "l", 3: "l", 4: "o", 5: " ", 6: "W", 7: "o", 8: "r", 9: "l", 10: "d"}
```

Say for example I'm now designing my own object; `Foo`

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo(value) {
        // Construct a foo object
    }
    return Foo;
})();

// Test
var foo = new Foo();
```

Okay, so I can call `Foo` as a constructor function, but how do I implement `Foo` as a standard function call, like so

```
var foo = Foo(myValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `String`, `Bolean` and `Number` there is no difference since internally they resolve to a constructor call. they are defined in the language in wich the javascript interpreter is written in (most of the time c++) so they differ to usual javascript objects / functions / constructors even though they behave like them.